# Debian testing and RabbitMQ - upgrading

Tags: debian, rabbitmq

I've got a simple problem with RabbitMQ on debian testing. The service works fine and I'm happy with it, but when it upgrades, it loses all it's exchanges, queues and, most importantly, permissions. Is there a way to migrate users and permissions across major version upgrades? I've googled quite a lot, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Do not let important tools get upgraded by the OS packaging system. Do it manually. Test it first on another machine. There should be no issues with upgrading RabbitMQ if you only upgrade the binaries and scripts which are in $RABBIT_HOME/ebin and $RABBIT_HOME/scripts in the tarballs produced by RabbitMQ developers. Any persistent queues will be picked up when the new versions starts up.